Why is dpkg-divert via devhekper not creating symlink?
I am creating a metapackage using debgelper and I seem to have my config files correct:
ls sys/etc/apache2
apache2.conf.dmsystem  sites-available

cat debian/displace
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf.dmsystem

My package is named dmsystem-www which sets up apache with a custom configuration. sys is the directory from which all configuration files are copied. I run dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc to build the package with no errors. When I install the package the custom config file is in the right place but the diversion is not created. The original config file is still there with no link. This setup works correctly for other metapackages I have put together, so what's the matter with this one?
